# Probe request capturing with Scapy

Tags: python, linux, networking

This is a probe request packet sniffer using python/scapy. It sniffs Dot11ProbeReq packets and display the ssid, MAC of device and manufacturer name from the probe requests. Can also output the data to a log file if desired. Right now I feel the script is a bit slow and I can see it slow down from the first time I wrote it. It works but I know the code is nowhere as efficient as it could be. Can you point out my mistakes and let me know how I can write more efficient code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# import all the needed libraries
import sys
from netaddr import *
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *
from subprocess import *
import datetime
import time

# clear the console
call(["clear"])                                           

# set date-time parameters                                                          
today = datetime.date.today()                 
d=today.strftime("%d, %b %Y")
tf=time.strftime(" %H:%M")
t=time.strftime(" %H:%M:%S")

# define variables                                                          
clients = []                          
uni = 0
mach = []
manu =[]

# our packet handler                                                          
def phandle(p):                       
    global uni    
    if p.haslayer(Dot11ProbeReq):                         
        mac = str(p.addr2)
        if p.haslayer(Dot11Elt):                          
            if p.ID == 0: 
                ssid = p.info                             
                if ssid not in clients and ssid != "":
                    clients.append(ssid)          
                    maco = EUI(mac)
            macf = maco.oui.registration().org   
            print len(clients),mac+" ("+macf+") <--Probing--> "+ssid
            if args.log:
                f.write (str(len(clients))+" "+mac+" ("+macf+") //"+" <--Probing--> "+ssid+"\n")
                if mac not in mach:
                            mach.append(mac)
                            uni+=1                                      
            elif mac not in mach:
            mach.append(mac)
                        uni+=1                           

# our main function             
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyRobe Help')
    parser.add_argument('interface', action="store", help="specify interface (ex. mon0)", default=False)
    parser.add_argument("-l","--log", dest="log",action="store_true", help="print log file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.log:
        f = open("ProbeLog"+str(today)+str(tf)+".txt","w")    
        sniff(iface=args.interface,prn=phandle, store=0)                    
            print ("\n")
            print "Unique MACs: ",uni
        f.write ("\nUnique MACs: "+str(uni))
        f.write ("\nScan performed on: "+str(d)+" at"+str(t))  
        f.close()                                                 
        print "Log successfully written. Exiting!"
    else:
        sniff(iface=args.interface,prn=phandle, store=0)
        print "\nSuccessfully Exited! No log file written."
```

I am basically looking for pointers on:

- Handling command line arguments better
- Calculating and assigning required memory/avoid leaks
- Shortening the code to make it faster to execute

I am not looking for someone to edit my script and spoon feed me the solution, just point me in the right direction!

- My Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) [GCC 4.7.2]
- My linux version: Distributor ID:Kali Description:Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0 Release:1.1.0 Codename:moto Linux version 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 gcc version 4.7.2 Debian 4.7.2-5) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02)

Comment: for simple argument and flag parsing you dont need arg parse, you've already imported `sys` from which you can call `sys.argv`which return argument variable string which you can then search for specific flags/arguments. It will reduce your syntax code and your memory of code since then you only need a comment that describes your flag and that is it.

Answer (score 5):

**Code style**

Always mention what exactly you are importing - never use `import *` - I don't know these libraries and when I read this for the first time I need to find all possible places where these methods can be from: `call`, `sniff`. If you want to write code which other people can read - always import exactly what you are using:

```
from netaddr import *
```

Be consistent when you are importing: `import argparse` is imported in main function which is really unnecessary - import on top with other imports.

Also  - this is picky but it is more readable to have imports in alphabetical order and not mixed with other code like `logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

String formatting is awful and not-readable:

Instead of:

```
str(len(clients))+" "+mac+" ("+macf+") //"+" <--Probing--> "+ssid+"\n"
```

Use `format` method:

```
"{0} mac {1}".format(len(clients), macf)
```

Or - even more readable:

```
"{length} mac {macf}".format(
    length=len(clients),
    macf=macf,
 )
```

Much more readable and is actually a standard.

Formatting (indentations) is a bit off - difficult to understand some pieces.

**Performance**

You have `mach` is list and you are constantly searching in it. Search in list is `O(n)`. Make is `set` or `dict` - will speed it up - search performance becomes `O(1)`.

```
mach = []
# this check is expensive
if mac not in mach:
```

Same comment  - for `clients` list.

Here - remove condition, just leave `else` - or maybe your formatting is misleading here and I didn't understand logic correctly:

```
elif mac not in mach:
```